# mysql RAND() following by desc order

Tags: mysql

I am pulling a list of inns from a database. Some are upgraded which entitles them to show up at the top of the list. Currently the upgraded show in ascending order followed by the regular ones using the following:

```
SELECT Company FROM bandb Where BusinessState = '$State' AND BusinessCity = '$City' AND (Active = 'Web' OR Active = 'Name') ORDER by featured asc, Company asc
```

I need to change it so the upgraded inns show up in random order followed by the rest of the inns in ascending order but I am stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: I really, really hope those interpolated values are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I have a function that cleans them up before

Comment: The problem with "functions that clean them up" is they're usually wrong. SQL escaping should be explicit and blindingly obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT Company, IF(featured, rand(), 0) AS rand_position
FROM bandb
Where BusinessState = '$State' AND BusinessCity = '$City' AND (Active = 'Web' OR Active = 'Name')
ORDER by featured asc, rand_position DESC, Company asc
```

If the company's "featured", a random number is generated for their position, otherwise they get a `0`. Then you sort on that random field. Non-featured companies end up at the bottom, and the featured ones show up ordered by that random number.